# Lookup and replace column values using dplyr in r

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, vlookup

Although I found few discussions but couldn't find a proper solution within dplyr.

My main table consists of more than 50 columns and have 15 lookup tables. Each lookup tables has around 8-15 columns. I have multiple lookups to perform and since it becomes really messy with select statements (either by selecting or removing with a minus), I would like to be able to replace column values on the fly.

Is this possible using dplyr? I have provided below just a sample data for better understanding.

I would like to do VLOOKUP (like excel) with **city** in **table** with **lcity** in **lookup** and replace values of **city** with **newcity**.

```
> table <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), city = c("hyd","sbad","hyd","sbad","others","unknown"), rno = c(101,102,103,104,105,106),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>lookup <- data.frame(lcity = c("hyd","sbad","others","test"),newcity = c("nhyd","nsbad","nothers","ntest"),rating = c(10,20,40,55),newrating = c(100,200,400,550), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> table
  name    city rno
1    a     hyd 101
2    b    sbad 102
3    c     hyd 103
4    d    sbad 104
5    e  others 105
6    f unknown 106
> lookup
   lcity newcity rating newrating
1    hyd    nhyd     10       100
2   sbad   nsbad     20       200
3 others nothers     40       400
4   test   ntest     55       550
```

My output table should be

```
  name    city rno
1    a    nhyd 101
2    b   nsbad 102
3    c    nhyd 103
4    d   nsbad 104
5    e nothers 105
6    f    <NA> 106
```

I have tried below code for updating values on the fly, but this creates another dataframe/table instead of a character vector

```
table$city <- select(left_join(table,lookup,by=c("city"="lcity")),"newcity")
```

Comment: Column `newcity` is missed in your syntax to create `lookup` dataframe. You should correct otherwise it will confuse other reader here. Thanks.

Comment: sorry.. updated it now. thanks

Comment: Very good. Thanks. My answer can solve it. I hope.

Comment: Unfortunately initially some time was lost in figuring out reason for strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

Note: The data shown by OP and created with commands are different for `lookup`. I have used the data shown for `lookup` in tabular format by OP.

```
library(dplyr)
# Data from OP
table <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 
    city = c("hyd","sbad","hyd","sbad","others","unknown"), 
 rno = c(101,102,103,104,105,106),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
lookup <- data.frame(lcity = c("hyd","sbad","others","test"), 
newcity = c("nhyd","nsbad","nothers","ntest"), 
rating = c(10,20,40,55),newrating = c(100,200,400,550), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table %>% 
  inner_join(lookup, by = c("city" = "lcity")) %>%
  mutate(city = newcity) %>%
  select(name,   city, rno)

  name    city rno
1    a    nhyd 101
2    b   nsbad 102
3    c    nhyd 103
4    d   nsbad 104
5    e nothers 105
```

Comment: sorry about the lookup dataframe error.. fixed it now. The problem with the select statement in my case is that I have around 40-50 columns and its gets updated at various stages. Is there any other alternative instead of calling individual column names

Comment: @Sat you can simply ignore the column which you dont want. Or first have a look without `select` and you will know which columns to remove.

Comment: @Sat You can replace `select` as `select( -newcity, -rating, -newrating)` in my answer and result will be same.

Comment: I should have been more clear earlier. Appreciate that your code works as expected. But I have many such lookups to perform and have around 15 lookup tables. Each lookup tables has around 8-15 columns. Since it becomes really messy with select statements, I wanted to see an alternative to replace.

Comment: I completely understand, but unfortunately I can't share the original data and creating so many lookups is a tedious job, so just provided a sample. I will wait for other to have a think may be. however I've edited my main query.